# How can I get access to application actions using TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I tried to look for answers, but couldn't find. I want to write a function to delete a previously used test organization before I start my tests in testcafe.

It's quite a time-consuming action if to make it through UI. So I wonder if it is possible to use app actions and write a function to delete my test data?

My thoughts are to perform the next steps:
1. find all test organizations I want to delete
2. iterate through each of them, call ShowDeleteOrgModal() method, and after that call DeleteOrganisation() method.

I saw other test tools provide access to application actions using window().
Is there any way I can implement it in testCafe?

The button selector looks like this.

```html
<button class="button_class" onclick="OurApplicationName.ShowDeleteOrgModal('organisation_id');
return false;">Delete Organisation</button>
```

We had implemented similar idea in cypress this way:

```
CleanUpOrgs() {
         cy.window().then((win) => {
         let numberOfOrgs = win.window.$('tr:contains(' + Cypress.env('testOrgName') + ')').length;
            while (numberOfOrgs > 0) {
                cy.get('table').contains('tr', Cypress.env('testOrgName')).then(elem => {
                    let orgId = elem[0].id.replace('OurApplicationName_', '');
                    cy.window().then((win) => {
                        win.window.OurApplicationName.ShowDeleteOrgModal(orgId);
                        win.window.OurApplicationName.DeleteOrganisation();
                        cy.wait(2000);
                    });
                });
                numberOfOrgs--;
            }
        });
    },
```

How can I get access to the window using TestCafe?

Answer (score 7):

Try using [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/). For example, you can open your modal with the following code:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const showDeleteOrgModal = ClientFunction(organizationId => {
    OurApplicationName.ShowDeleteOrgModal(organizationId);
});

fixture`My fixture`
    .page`http://www.example.com/`;

test('My Test', async t => {
    await showDeleteOrgModal('organisation_id');
});
```

You can also [run the asynchronous code](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#running-asynchronous-client-code) on the client side this way.

---

UPDATE
I can't provide you with an exact test without access to the testing page.
But I've created an example how this test can look like

```js
import { ClientFunction, Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
import { testOrgName } from './config';

fixture`fixture`
    .page`http://url`;

const trElSelector = Selector('table').find('tr').withText(testOrgName);

const cleanUpOrg = ClientFunction(() => {
    const trElement = trElSelector();
    const orgId     = trElement.id.replace('OurApplicationName_', '');

    window.OurApplicationName.ShowDeleteOrgModal(orgId);
    window.OurApplicationName.DeleteOrganisation();
}, { dependencies: { trElSelector } });

async function cleanUpAllOrgs () {
    const numberOfOrgs = await Selector('tr').withText(testOrgName).length;

    for (let i = numberOfOrgs; i > 0; i--) {
        await cleanUpOrg();
        await t.wait(200);
    }
}

test('test', async t => {
    await cleanUpAllOrgs();
});
```

I used [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/), [Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) and the config file for the `testOrgName` variable (you can learn more about using configurations and environment variables in [FAQ](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#how-do-i-work-with-configuration-files-and-environment-variables)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this approach today!

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting an error "Property doesn't exist on type window".

Comment: Arseniy, I've added an example of the cypress code we used into my main question description. Could you advise , how I can convert it to use it in testcafe?

Comment: Yulia, the most part of your code is getting the required element on the client side. Since ClientFunctions allows you to write you code completely in JS, you do not need any TestCafe specifics to get the element. You can use the standard JS functions like `document.querySelector`, etc.

As for the "Property doesn't exist on type window" error, it's difficult to determine the cause of the issue. Arseniy's approach should work correctly. Please share your test code and the url to your project. You can also send it at support@devexpress.com